# Auto fit boxes to fit to page

Tags: tcolorbox, fit

I am trying to overcome an issue that I am having. I want the colorboxes to fit onto a page without over running the footer or page and starting again on the next page. Is there a way that I can do this.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions and solutions

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{grffile} %Stops the file name of figures appearing
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\officialeuro}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\text\fi
  {\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eurosym}\selectfont e}}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\title{Business Plan}
\author{}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{algorithmic}
 \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\textheight=23cm \textwidth=16cm \topmargin=-2cm \oddsidemargin=0cm
\parindent=0mm
\pretolerance=2000 \tolerance=3000

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries %glossaries

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  color=black,
  opacity=1,
  angle=0,
  position=current page.south,
  vshift=60pt,
  contents={%
  \small\sffamily%
  \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
  \parbox[b]{.6\textwidth}{%
    Page \thepage\ of   \pageref{LastPage}}\hfill
  \parbox[b]{.4\textwidth}{%
    \raggedleft xxxx \\ xxx, xxx}\      \textcolor{red}{\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\      \url{www.xxx.co.uk}
  \end{minipage}\hspace{.02\textwidth}%
  \begin{minipage}{.18\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=70pt,keepaspectratio]{iPhone app}
  \end{minipage}%
  }
}

\tcbset{rawlings/.style={width=\textwidth,colback={white},colbacktitle=SkyBlue,coltitle=black,colupper=black}}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,list inside=rawlings]{rawlingsbox}[1][]{rawlings,#1}%

\begin{document}

\begin{rawlingsbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={white},colbacktitle=red,coltitle=white,colupper=black,title={\textbf{Executive Summary}},title={\textbf{Conclusions}}]
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
aa\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
aa\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
aa\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
\end{rawlingsbox}


\end{document}
```

Comment: tcolorbox library `breakable` and then option `breakable`.

Comment: You could use `\usepackage{blindtext}` and `\blindtext[8]` for example to show a huge box, that should be broken instead of a bunch of `a\\` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add the required `breakable` option as in

```
\tcbset{rawlings/.style={breakable,width=\textwidth,colback={white},colbacktitle=SkyBlue,coltitle=black,colupper=black}}
```

[image: break]

*Update:* For your title after break add `title after break` as in

```
\begin{rawlingsbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={white},colbacktitle=red,coltitle=white,colupper=black,title={\textbf{Conclusions}},title after break={\textbf{Conclusions}}]
```

[image: updated image]

You should really read the documentation at least once to get an imagination what is possible with tcb.

Comment: Thank you very much that is great, Is there a way to still keep the heading for the box on the break away box? :)

Comment: @DanielRawlings `title after break=`.

Comment: @DanielRawlings: There is `title after break` option